# How do I install pcre with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, pcre

**Background**

I have a regex I want to run across multiple lines. My understanding is that OSX's grep can't handle this (please correct me if I'm wrong!). So after some Googling I found that PCRE would do what I want. I tried to install it with `brew install pcre` as a few sites suggested. It seems to have worked. If I run `brew install pcre` again I get this error `Warning: pcre-8.40 already installed` and I have a `/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.40/` directory.

**Problem**

After installing PCRE via homebrew I get this error `pcre: command not found` when I try to use the `pcre` command.

**Questions**

Is there a second step I need to run after `brew install pcre`? I didn't find anything listed for this, but perhaps I missed it. I also found [these instructions](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/pcre/) for installing PCRE manually. Is there a downside to doing this over homebrew?

Comment: Try running 'brew link pcre' it may be that it is installed but homebrew decided not to add it to your PATH in order to avoid conflicts with existing system software. or you could manually add the path to pcre to your PATH

Comment: @AlexZywicki Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately when I tried that brew said it was already linked. So I tried to unlink and then link it again. The link happened, but I still get the `pcre: command not found` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`homebrew-core/pcre` package is shipped with these binaries, so you probably need to try them:

- `pcre-config`
- `pcregrep`
- `pcretest`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I needed to use `pcregrep` not just `pcre`! Cheers :D