# Can't grep stack trace from heroku logs

Tags: php, regex, heroku, logging, grep

I'm trying to write a script that returns stack traces from heroku logs.

Here's an example output I would like to capture:

````
```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid authentication source: name' in /app/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Default.php:61
2018-10-18T20:36:09.617037+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2018-10-18T20:36:09.617384+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php(136): SimpleSAML_Auth_Default::initLogin('sp-name', '...', NULL, Array)
2018-10-18T20:36:09.617681+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/config.php(21): SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple->login(Array)
2018-10-18T20:36:09.618083+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/config.php(38): getSAMLUser('urn:oasis:names...')
2018-10-18T20:36:09.618337+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/login.php(35): getSAMLUserErrorChecking('...')
2018-10-18T20:36:09.618343+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 {main}
2018-10-18T20:36:09.618465+00:00 app[web.1]:   thrown in /app/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Default.php on line 61
2018-10-18T20:38:48.323247+00:00 heroku[router]:
```
````

I've been trying to use the following to capture the important bits:

`heroku logs -t -a appname | grep '(?<=PHP Fatal error)(.*)(?=router)'`

*edit* Here's a proof of concept for the regex I'm using here: https://regex101.com/r/EpCwE0/1

Comment: Try `grep -Poz '(?<=PHP Fatal error).*?(?=router)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew running that as the filter returns:
```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```
For some reason I don't have the -Poz options? Perhaps it's because I'm on mac os

Comment: Ah, you need `pcregrep`. Install [via homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112312/how-do-i-install-pcre-with-homebrew).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It appears that I have it installed, I tried running:
`heroku logs -t -a redacted | pcregrep -Poz '(?<=PHP Fatal error).*?(?=router)'`

returns:

```pcregrep: Unknown option letter 'P' in "-Poz"
Usage: pcregrep [-AaBCcDdeFfHhIilLMNnoqrsuVvwx] [long options] [pattern] [files]
Type `pcregrep --help' for more information and the long options.
```

Comment: Yeah, you do not need `P` I guess, since it is already `pcregrep`.

Comment: Sadly,
`heroku logs -t -a redacted | pcregrep -o '(?<=PHP Fatal error).*?(?=router)'`
didn't catch anything, : /

Comment: ```
heroku logs -t -a redacted | pcregrep -oz '(?<=PHP Fatal error).*?(?=router)'
pcregrep: Unknown option letter 'z' in "-oz"
Usage: pcregrep [-AaBCcDdeFfHhIilLMNnoqrsuVvwx] [long options] [pattern] [files]
Type `pcregrep --help' for more information and the long options.
```

Comment: Try `sed -n '/^PHP Fatal error/,/router/p'` instead

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does `pcregrep` have a `z` option?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't catch the result either. Hmm..

Comment: pcregrep does not have a `z` option

Comment: remove `^` from the suggested `sed` command.

Comment: Is `PHP Fatal error` at the start of a line? How many such matches in the file do you expect: one or more? Is it ok to only return a whole block of lines with the delimiters containing inside them?

Comment: @revo It worked!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew after removing the `^` from the pattern, I got the expected result :)))

Comment: That is because it was not clear if that text is at the start of the line or not.

Comment: @revo You should write up an answer since OP says your alternative solution worked

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because the problem isn't just select between two strings.. It's selecting over a stream of input...